# COUNT Number of properties sold against their respective types?

Tags: sql, function, count, ms-access-2007

I'm quite new to SQL and I'm trying to figure out how I can get this result:

```
Type                   Number Sold
Detached                    5
Semi-detached               2
Terrace                     1
Link                        8
```

Using a query, I have tried:

```
  SELECT SPropertyType AS Type, COUNT (SPropertyCurrentState) AS NumberSold
  FROM SaleProperty
  WHERE SPropertyCurrentState = 'Sold';
```

But it gave me an error.

Comment: can you add table schema

Comment: What error do you get and which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to add `group by SPropertyType` clause

the final SQL will look like this

```
 SELECT 
    SPropertyType AS Type, 
    COUNT (SPropertyCurrentState) AS NumberSold
  FROM SaleProperty
  WHERE 
    SPropertyCurrentState = 'Sold'
  GROUP BY 
    SPropertyType;
```

Comment: I have tried doing that but I still have an error saying 'You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Type' as part of an aggregate function'

Comment: can you add the table schema , and can you check and execute the sql i included

Comment: I got a different error saying 'Characters found after end of SQL Statement'

Comment: what is you database engine "MS SQL, MYSQL ... etc"?

Comment: SQL, using Access 2007

Comment: Try it again, I fixed a couple minor typos

Answer (score 0):

You forget to use GROUP BY.
Use this:

```
SELECT
    SPropertyType AS Type,
    COUNT (SPropertyCurrentState) AS NumberSold
FROM
    SaleProperty
WHERE
    Upper(SPropertyCurrentState) = 'SOLD'
GROUP BY
    SPropertyType;
```